# Some advanced analytics on a hierarchical SQL query

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this little schema. The `my_item_lab` table represents items with their denomination in English and French.

```
drop table my_item_lib;

create table my_item_lib
(
    id_item number,
    lib_fr  varchar2(100),
    lib_en  varchar2(100)
);

insert into my_item_lib values (1, '1_fr', '1_en');
insert into my_item_lib values (2, '2_fr', '2_en');
insert into my_item_lib values (3, '3_fr', '3_en');
insert into my_item_lib values (4, '4_fr', '4_en');
insert into my_item_lib values (5, '5_fr', '5_en');
insert into my_item_lib values (6, '6_fr', '6_en');
insert into my_item_lib values (7, '7_fr', '7_en');
insert into my_item_lib values (8, '8_fr', '8_en');
insert into my_item_lib values (9, '9_fr', '9_en');
insert into my_item_lib values (10, '10_fr', '10_en');
```

The `my_item_hierarchy` represents an hierarchy between items.

```
drop table my_item_hierarchy;

create table my_item_hierarchy
(
    id_item     number,
    id_item_sup number,
    ordre       number
);

insert into my_item_hierarchy values (1, null, 1);
insert into my_item_hierarchy values (2, 1, 2);
insert into my_item_hierarchy values (3, 2, 3);
insert into my_item_hierarchy values (4, 3, 4);
insert into my_item_hierarchy values (5, 3, 5);
insert into my_item_hierarchy values (6, 4, 6);
insert into my_item_hierarchy values (7, 4, 7);
insert into my_item_hierarchy values (8, 2, 8);
insert into my_item_hierarchy values (9, 1, 9);
insert into my_item_hierarchy values (10, 9, 10);
```

I am writing this query to get, for each item, its parent, grand parent and great grand parent.

```
select *
from
(
    with v00 as
    (
        select  
        a.id_item       
        , lib.lib_fr
        , lib.lib_en
        -- --
        , a.id_item_sup
        , lib_sup.lib_fr lib_fr_sup
        , lib_sup.lib_en lib_en_sup
        from my_item_hierarchy a
        , my_item_lib lib
        , my_item_lib lib_sup
        where 1 = 1
        and a.id_item = lib.id_item
        and a.id_item_sup = lib_sup.id_item(+)
    ), h as
    (
        select 
        connect_by_root id_item id_item
        , id_item_sup
        , level lvl
        from v00
        where 1 = 1
        connect by 
        id_item = prior id_item_sup 
        and level <= 3
    )
    select id_item
    , id_item_sup1, id_item_sup2, id_item_sup3
    from h
    pivot (max(id_item_sup) for lvl in (1 as id_item_sup1, 2 as id_item_sup2, 3 as id_item_sup3))
    order by 1
)
;

   ID_ITEM ID_ITEM_SUP1 ID_ITEM_SUP2 ID_ITEM_SUP3
---------- ------------ ------------ ------------
         1
         2            1
         3            2            1
         4            3            2            1
         5            3            2            1
         6            4            3            2
         7            4            3            2
         8            2            1
         9            1
        10            9            1
```

Now, how can I modify the query so I can get this output :

```
   ID_ITEM ID_ITEM_SUP1 ID_ITEM_SUP2 ID_ITEM_SUP3 LIB_EN_SUP1     LIB_EN_SUP2     LIB_EN_SUP3
---------- ------------ ------------ ------------ --------------- --------------- ---------------
         1                                        
         2            1                           1_en
         3            2            1              2_en            1_en           
         4            3            2            1 3_en            2_en             1_en
         5            3            2            1 3_en            2_en             1_en
         6            4            3            2 4_en            3_en             2_en
         7            4            3            2 4_en            3_en             2_en
         8            2            1              2_en            1_en   
         9            1                           1_en
        10            9            1              9_en            1_en
```

I am using Oracle 11.2.0.3.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```sql
SELECT "1_ID_ITEM" AS id_item,
       "2_ID_ITEM" AS id_item_sup1,
       "3_ID_ITEM" AS id_item_sup2,
       "4_ID_ITEM" AS id_item_sup3,
       "1_LIB_EN" AS lib_en,
       "2_LIB_EN" AS lib_en_sup1,
       "3_LIB_EN" AS lib_en_sup2,
       "4_LIB_EN" AS lib_en_sup3,
       "1_LIB_FR" AS lib_fr,
       "2_LIB_FR" AS lib_fr_sup1,
       "3_LIB_FR" AS lib_fr_sup2,
       "4_LIB_FR" AS lib_fr_sup3
FROM   (
  SELECT CONNECT_BY_ROOT l.id_item AS root_item,
         l.id_item,
         l.lib_en,
         l.lib_fr,
         LEVEL AS lvl
  FROM   my_item_hierarchy h
         INNER JOIN my_item_lib l
         ON (h.id_item = l.id_item)
  WHERE  LEVEL <= 4
  CONNECT BY l.id_item = PRIOR h.id_item_sup
)
PIVOT (
  MAX(id_item) AS id_item,
  MAX(lib_en) AS lib_en,
  MAX(lib_fr) AS lib_fr
  FOR lvl IN (1,2,3,4)
)
ORDER BY id_item;
```

Which outputs:

| ID_ITEM | ID_ITEM_SUP1 | ID_ITEM_SUP2 | ID_ITEM_SUP3 | LIB_EN | LIB_EN_SUP1 | LIB_EN_SUP2 | LIB_EN_SUP3 | LIB_FR | LIB_FR_SUP1 | LIB_FR_SUP2 | LIB_FR_SUP3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | *null* | *null* | *null* | 1_en | *null* | *null* | *null* | 1_fr | *null* | *null* | *null* |
| 2 | 1 | *null* | *null* | 2_en | 1_en | *null* | *null* | 2_fr | 1_fr | *null* | *null* |
| 3 | 2 | 1 | *null* | 3_en | 2_en | 1_en | *null* | 3_fr | 2_fr | 1_fr | *null* |
| 4 | 3 | 2 | 1 | 4_en | 3_en | 2_en | 1_en | 4_fr | 3_fr | 2_fr | 1_fr |
| 5 | 3 | 2 | 1 | 5_en | 3_en | 2_en | 1_en | 5_fr | 3_fr | 2_fr | 1_fr |
| 6 | 4 | 3 | 2 | 6_en | 4_en | 3_en | 2_en | 6_fr | 4_fr | 3_fr | 2_fr |
| 7 | 4 | 3 | 2 | 7_en | 4_en | 3_en | 2_en | 7_fr | 4_fr | 3_fr | 2_fr |
| 8 | 2 | 1 | *null* | 8_en | 2_en | 1_en | *null* | 8_fr | 2_fr | 1_fr | *null* |
| 9 | 1 | *null* | *null* | 9_en | 1_en | *null* | *null* | 9_fr | 1_fr | *null* | *null* |
| 10 | 9 | 1 | *null* | 10_en | 9_en | 1_en | *null* | 10_fr | 9_fr | 1_fr | *null* |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/OVbQGQ1j)

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```sql
select i.id_item as iid, p.id_item as pid, g.id_item as gid, h.id_item as hid,
  lp.lib_en as lib_en_sup1,
  lg.lib_en as lib_en_sup2,
  lh.lib_en as lib_en_sup3  
from my_item_hierarchy i
left join my_item_hierarchy p on p.id_item = i.id_item_sup
left join my_item_hierarchy g on g.id_item = p.id_item_sup
left join my_item_hierarchy h on h.id_item = g.id_item_sup
left join my_item_lib lp on lp.id_item = p.id_item
left join my_item_lib lg on lg.id_item = g.id_item
left join my_item_lib lh on lh.id_item = h.id_item
order by 1
```

Result:

```
 IID  PID   GID   HID   LIB_EN_SUP1  LIB_EN_SUP2  LIB_EN_SUP3 
 ---- ----- ----- ----- ------------ ------------ ----------- 
 1    null  null  null  null         null         null        
 2    1     null  null  1_en         null         null        
 3    2     1     null  2_en         1_en         null        
 4    3     2     1     3_en         2_en         1_en        
 5    3     2     1     3_en         2_en         1_en        
 6    4     3     2     4_en         3_en         2_en        
 7    4     3     2     4_en         3_en         2_en        
 8    2     1     null  2_en         1_en         null        
 9    1     null  null  1_en         null         null        
 10   9     1     null  9_en         1_en         null
```

See running example at [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/vsgkSzuG).